# Update PostgreSQL tables with one SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I have these two tables which I would like to update with one SQL query using Java code:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
 PASSWD TEXT,
 FIRST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_NAME TEXT,
 E_MAIL TEXT NOT NULL,
 COUNTRY TEXT,
 STATE TEXT,
 LAST_PASSWD_RESET DATE,
 DESCRIPTION TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT USER_NAME UNIQUE (USER_NAME)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT E_MAIL UNIQUE (E_MAIL)
;

-- TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
 ROLE INTEGER,
 PERMISSION TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP19 ON ACCOUNT_ROLE (ID)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT KEY26 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP19 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES ACCOUNT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

I use this SQL query to update first table data. For the second table I use similar SQL query:

```
UPDATE ACCOUNT SET ID = ?, USER_NAME = ?, PASSWD = ?, FIRST_NAME = ?, LAST_NAME = ?, E_MAIL = ?, COUNTRY = ?, STATE = ?, " CITY = ?, ADDRESS = ?, STATUS = ?, SECURITY_QUESTION = ?, SECURITY_ANSWER = ?, DESCRIPTION = ?, LAST_UPDATED = CURRENT_DATE WHERE ID = ?
```

How this can solve this?

Comment: Solve what?  You seem to understand how to write an `update` statement.

Comment: Correct but how to update two tables with one SQL query?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: why do you think you need to do that in a single statement? Why not simply run two `update` statements if you want to update two tables?

Comment: Because if one SQL statement fails I need to rowback both SQL inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can update two tables by using CTEs:

```
with t1 as (
      update . . .
      returning *
     )
update t2
    . . .
```

It is unclear how this fits into what you are trying to do.  But it is possible to write one statement in Postgres that does two updates.

Answer (score 1):

[you can't](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html) unless you have two tables that use [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html)

I do not know any SQL DB that will allow changes to two or more tables at the same time.

Not sure if you will ever need such a functionality.

If you would like to keep changes together - just open a [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html) and put those two updates together, if one will fail, whole transaction can be rolled-back.

Of course one can use [explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html) with `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` which is fine too.

If you are looking something to simplify code - maybe you should look at [stored procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql.html), so you will be able to write complex code and call it with some parameters.

Comment: Postgres _can_ update two tables in a single statement using data modifying CTEs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING